# Grab data (preferably using JSON format) of how much data traffic is leaving and coming into my computer?

Tags: windows, command-line, network-monitor, statistics, bandwidth

Windows 10. Would prefer if this is built-in, but if it's trustworthy and free, I could use a third-party program.

I'm looking for something which will let me grab data (preferably in JSON format) such as:

1. Total incoming bytes.
2. Total outgoing bytes.
3. Incoming bytes for program X.
4. Outgoing bytes for program X.
5. Incoming bytes for protocol X.
6. Outgoing bytes for protocol X.

And I want it to let me reset the stats at any time.

It doesn't need a GUI, but it does need to be straight-forward and not cryptic.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As we recommend software here (not [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185) or "internal functions"), it will probably be a 3rd party solution. I've slightly adjusted the title of your question to avoid it from being closed as off-topic. Good luck!